# Can Not Set Toastr Message From Controller in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, toastr

I want to display toastr message from controller for that i [Preferred Link](http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/create-an-mvc-wrapper-for-toastr/)  but not working properly.

i pass message from controller like this

```
this.AddToastMessage("", "Menu Added Successfully", ToastType.Success);
```

message pass to view ... for that see my screenshot number 1

[image: Screenshot 1]

But When I pass value to my helper class it will pass null i dont know how.?for that see my screenshot 2

[image: Screenshot 2]

What i am doing wrong.? can anyone help me out.?

Comment: The first step would be to look at the actual type of `TempData["Toastr"]`. What does `TempData["Toastr"].GetType()` return?

Comment: @ershoaib .. can u please help me out.?

Comment: What is the type of TempData["Toastr"] ? is it a string or Toastr?

Comment: @Arjun Prakash .. i declare as Toastr. as u can see in my code

Comment: @NiharikaJagani, I was successfully implemented `Toastr` in my side, lets see what happens at your side

Comment: @ershoaib ...okay how you did this.?

Comment: did u create an partial view for this `@using MyWebApplication.Toast 
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("Toastr")) 
{ 
Toastr toastr = TempData["Toastr"] as Toastr; 
@ToastrBuilder.ShowToastMessages(toastr); 
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178728/discussion-between-niharikajagani-and-ershoaib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partial view with name `_Toastr.cshtml` in your Shared folder where your `_Layout.cshtml`  present.

And paste below code

```
@using WebApplicationMVC1.Models
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("Toastr"))
{
    Toastr toastr = TempData["Toastr"] as Toastr;
    @ToastrBuilder.ShowToastMessages(toastr);
}
```

And call this partial view on your `_Layout.cshtml` page in below of `RenderSection` line like

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

@Html.Partial("_Toastr")
```

Comment: glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)